# Prove by mathematical induction that $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$ for all natural number $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I'm working on a task where I'm a bit unsure if the answer I've got is correct.

Here is the task:

> *Show by induction that the following assertion is true for all natural
>   numbers $n$*
>
> $n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$

Here is my answer:

> For $n = 1$,
>   $n^3 - n = 1 - 1$
>   which is divisible by $3$
>
> Assume the statement is true for some number $n$, that is, $n^3 - n$
>   is divisible by $3$. Now,
>
> $(n + 1)^3 - (n + 1) = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 - n - 1 = (n^3 - n) + 3(n^2 + n) = (n^3 - n) + 3n(n+1)$
>
> which is $n^3 - n$ plus a multiple of $3$.
>
> Since we assumed that $n^3 - n$ was a multiple of $3$, it follows that
>   $(n + 1)^3 - (n + 1)$ is also a multiple of $3$.
>
> So, since the statement "$n^3 - n$ is divisible by $3$" is true for $n
>  = 1$, and its truth for $n$ implies its truth for $n + 1$, the statement is true for all whole number $n$.

I would appreciate if someone could go through the task and the answer and see if I've done this correctly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: You are right. But one can prove simplier without induction, if you will consider a decomposition $n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)$.

Comment: To add on to Boris' statement: _one_ of $n-1$, $n$ and $n+1$ _must_ be divisible by three since they are three consecutive integers.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591881/prove-by-induction-vphantom-large-a3-mid-leftn3-n-right

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$$
\pars{n + 1}^{3} - \pars{n + 1}
=
\pars{n^{3} - n} + 3n\pars{n + 1}
$$

Comment: How does this differ from OP's answer?